# Is there a lower bound for $N$ such that the linear span of $N$ linearly independent matrices $\in C^{n\times n}$ contains at least one rank 1 matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $N$ linearly independent matrices in $C^{n\times n}$, is there a lower bound known for $N$ as a function of $n$ such that the linear span of those $N$ matrices is guaranteed to contain a rank 1 matrix?

Answer (score 7):

The set of rank $1$ matrices is a projective variety of dimension $2n-2$ inside the projective space over $C^{n \times n}$, which has dimension $n^2-1$. By the projective dimension theorem, it must intersect every projective variety of dimension $k$ whenever $2n-2+k > n^2-1$. The linear span of $N$ linearly independent matrices is a projective variety of dimension $k=N-1$. Therefore, if $N > (n-1)^2$, your span contains a rank $1$ matrix.

This is sharp: a generic subspace of dimension $(n-1)^2$ does not contain a rank $1$ matrix.

This question is fundamental in quantum information theory, where we want to find subspaces of $\mathbf{C}^n \otimes \mathbf{C}^n$ where every element is (very) entangled. See for example Chapter 8.1 of our book.

*Aubrun, Guillaume; Szarek, Stanisław J.*, [**Alice and Bob meet Banach. The interface of asymptotic geometric analysis and quantum information theory**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/surv/223), Mathematical Surveys and Monographs 223. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS) (ISBN 978-1-4704-3468-7/hbk; 978-1-4704-4172-2/ebook). xxi, 414 p. (2017). [ZBL1402.46001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1402.46001).

Comment: HI Guillaume ! Amazingly, this problem arises also, but replacing the complex field $\mathbb C$ by the real one $\mathbb R$, in Calculus of Variations, when one applies the technique of Compensated Compactness. One of my first papers was about that : *Formes quadratiques et calcul des varaiations*, J. Maths Pures & Appl. **62** (1983), pp 177-196.

Comment: Hi Denis! Interesting. Let $N_{\mathbb{K}}(n)$ is the largest dimension of a subspace of $\mathbb{K}^{n \times n}$ not containing a rang $1$ matrix. We have $N_{\mathbb{R}}(n) \geq N_{\mathbb{C}}(n)$ since the lower bound arguments work for $\mathbb{R}$ as well. Also, $2=N_\mathbb{R}(2)>N_\mathbb{C}(2)=1$. Is the value of $N_{\mathbb{R}}(n)$ known ?

Comment: thanks a lot Guillaume, this is exactly what I was looking for! I guess it is not constructive though, i.e. do you know of an algorithm which is guaranteed to find a rank 1 matrix?

Comment: I have no idea. There is an area of research called numerical algebraic geometry which may be related to what you ask, see e.g. Chapter 13 in the book "A.J. Sommese and C.W. Wampler, II,The Numerical Solution of Systems of Polynomials Arising in Engineering and Science"

Comment: @user40076 - There are algorithms that are guaranteed to find a rank-1 matrix if it exists (you can use the Parillo sum-of-squares SDP heirarchy, for example). However, the problem is extremely similar to problems that are known to be NP-hard (and it may well be known to be NP-hard), so I doubt there is an *efficient* algorithm.